# Spring Test ContextConfiguration inherit from Aplication context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

When loading a Spring Context for testing a Spring application e.g. something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes=MyTestConfig.class)
public class SpringTest {
```

Is it good practice to inherit the Spring Context from the app itself and override those configurations that are applicable to the tests?

Or should the test context be isolated from that of the application (which means I will have a copies of the same configuration in both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is best to break up the contexts into purpose based parts and then make use of Spring Profiles.  For example you will always have a Root context of domain stuff.  A web context has the dispatcherServlet resources.  And then the database beans can be in different Spring Profiles for test and run.  I say "run" because I don't like using seperate spring profiles for dev/qa/prod like some people recommend.  It seems easier to control this through JNDI, not Code.

I haven't done much with Mockito but my limited experience seems to say it fits in fairly well with this design.

Example JUNIT

```
@ActiveProfiles({"root","H2Test"})

@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {H2ContextConfig.class, 
    RootContextConfig.class}, loader = 
    AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TestDefectRepository {
...
```

The DataSource, EntityManager etc to make H2 go:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("H2Test")

public class H2ContextConfig {
```